# gnuplot: misinterpreting data (histogram)

Tags: gnuplot

I have following sample data file, which I want to plot in `gnuplot` as a histogram

```
1   1
2   2
4   3
```

I am using following command to plot the data: `plot "sample.data" with boxes`, which produces following chart:

```
      ##
      ##
  ######
  ######
########
########
```

whereas, the chart should look like this (there should be no value for `3`):

```
      ##
      ##
  ##  ##
  ##  ##
####  ##
####  ##
```

From `help boxwidth` I understand that: "By default, adjacent  boxes are extended in width until they touch each other". This seems like a serious bug/misfeature to me. I want my data to be represented correctly, and not to plot nonexistent data. How can I trust `gnuplot` to represent my data correctly, when this simple example fails?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you had read also the other sentences around it, you would have seen, that the boxes are calculated automatically only if no exlicit `boxwidth` was specified. This can be done either by using a third column, or by setting one width with `set boxwidth`:

```
set boxwidth 1
plot "sample.data" with boxes
```

or

```
plot "sample.data" using 1:2:(1) with boxes
```

Note, that the boxwidth is given in units of the x-axis.

Comment: thanks, that works. My point was, however, that if this is the way `gnuplot` behaves, how can I be sure in the future, that my data is displayed correctly? Why does it misinterpret data by default, and only when additional parameters are provided are the data displayed correctly. Will I always have to worry, that I have perhaps missed some parameter, and that my chart is garbage?

Comment: I don't know why this is the default, but it could be worth discussing it with the gnuplot developers as `set boxwidth` affects several plotting styles. It could be useful maybe to have a default of calculating the width automatically, but use the minimum width for all boxes. However, if you set a fixed box width in your scripts you know, that the chart is correct.

Comment: @Christoph This is nice, but makes the boxes quite ugly. They became thin vertical lines. Using `set boxwidth 5` did not help.

Comment: @Notinlist The box width as given in the `using` statement is in units of the x-axis. Also `set boxwidth 5` uses the x-axis units as reference. Using `set boxwidth 1 relative` uses a relative length, but that depends on the box spacing and isn't the same for all boxes.

Comment: @Christoph Thanks for the explanation. Tricky question: What is the X-axis unit when `set xdata time` and `set format x "%Y-%m"`?

Comment: @Christoph I have it! It's seconds. Which is a little bit inconvenient for variable length months, but eligible. `set borderwidth 28*24*60*60`

Comment: @Notinlist In that case the x-unit is seconds, which may explain why your boxes are so small